# What are some good resources for multi-class text classification using word2vec followed by SVM/ANN / Deep Networks?

Tags: nlp, deep-learning, text-classification, word2vec

I need to implement a multi-class text classifier. I thought of using word2vec, can someone lead me to good papers/resources which talk about this.
i would have 4-5 classes and I have loads of data. I have to manually label some of them. It would also be great if someone could throw light on the training size. I plan to use pre-trained word2vec for word embedding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MLP for this task, check [Keras' example](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/reuters_mlp.py) for classifying Reuters documents. You can add an embedding layer in the beginning of the model and load it with pretrained model weights.

Keep in mind that there is a multi-class classification which outputs a single class for each input and there is multi-label classification which might output many classes for each input (you didn't say anything about your data character so just letting you know).